# Procedural Textures Distorted

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

I was wondering what caused this weird texture distortion.
Every time I try to add noise or distortion using procedural textures, this happens
[image: distorted]
Before distortion it looks like this
[image: non distorted]
I want something like this
[image: plane]
Please help

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: That disturbance looks an awful lot like checker or 1x1 brick textures are mixed in somehow. They both treat generated and object coordinates like that background I see through the distorted wave. Can you expand the Base Color Wave Texture on the right, please?